# In a cyclic group, if order of two different elements are equal then is it true that the group generated by them are equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\langle a \rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. Let $a^r,a^s\in G, r\neq s.$ Let's assume that order($a^r$)= order($a^s$). Then is it true that $\langle a^r \rangle = \langle a^s\rangle.$

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. Denote $d=$ order$(a^r)=$ order$(a^s)$. Since the group $G$ is cyclic and finite, then it has exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for every divisor $d$ of $n$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups)). Since, the order of an element of a finite group divides the order of the group, i.e. $d\mid n$, this is the only case.

Comment: Your first statement is correct but in the 2nd statement if $a^r,a^s$ are generators then both have order n, so $d=n$ but your claim is $d$ is not a divisor of $n$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Saikat Yes, of course you are right. Actually there is no such case. The order of any element must divide the order of the group in a finite group.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: can you solve $(a^r)^k = a^s$?

Comment: No in general it can't be solved

Answer (score 0):

For a cyclic group $G$, the order of its generator is same as the order of the group. Now suppose $a$ generates $G_1$ and $b$ generates $G_2$ then $o(a)=o(G_1)$ and $o(b)=o(G_2)$. But since by the statement $o(a)=o(b)$, so $o(G_1)=o(G_2)$ and hence $G_1=G_2$.

Comment: your last statement is my question actually.